# How can I avoid acceleration/deceleration on Animator animations?

Tags: android, animator

I have created a chain of (up to 4) animations with the following code. They are all simple translations of several ImageViews at the same time.

After one animation "frame" (i.e. movement of all views), onAnimationEnd calls the next frame.

The problem is: there is a short but noticeable delay after each call of onAnimationEnd. It looks like there is an automatic acceleration and deceleration of the translations to make it look more natural, but this is unwanted in this case.
Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks in advance!

```
private void animateFrame(final int frame) {

    List<Animator> allAnimations = new ArrayList<>();
    AnimatorSet s = new AnimatorSet();

    for (int p = 0; p < playerImages.size(); p++) {

        Animator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(playerImages.get(p), "translationX", playerPositions[frame][0][p] * factorX);

        allAnimations.add(animation);
        ObjectAnimator animation2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(playerImages.get(p), "translationY", playerPositions[frame][1][p] * factorY);
        allAnimations.add(animation2);
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: MOVING PLAYER " + p + " TO: " + playerPositions[frame][0][p] + "/" + playerPositions[frame][1][p]);

        if (playerPositions[frame][0][p] != 0) {
            s.playTogether(allAnimations);

            s.setDuration(durations[frame - 1]);
            s.start();

            s.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    animateFrame(frame+1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [Property Animation Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation#interpolators)

> An interpolator define how specific values in an animation are calculated as a function of time. For example, you can specify animations to happen linearly across the whole animation, meaning the animation moves evenly the entire time, or you can specify animations to use non-linear time, for example, using acceleration or deceleration at the beginning or end of the animation.

The default Interpolator for property animations is the [`AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator.html). But you can set another Interpolator (any class implementing [`TimeInterpolator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeInterpolator)). From your question, I think you're looking for a `LinearInterpolator`:

```
animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```